# How can I detect whether .SetView() method's animation completes?

Tags: windows-phone-7, maps, windows-phone-8

How can I detect whether `.SetView()` method's animation completes in Windows Phone 8 Map? I want to execute some code after the animation. Otherwise if I do any manipulations with the map, the animation stops and doesn't continue anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the ViewChangedEvent handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.viewchanged(v=vs.105).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.mapviewchangedeventargs(v=vs.105).aspx